# How to use IN Clause for list of GUID's in Dapper Delete Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

How to use `in` clause in delete dapper query?

`DELETE FROM [tableName] where [columnName] in ({list of guids});`

I tried the below code, but I'm getting "unique identifier conversion" error:

```
//EmpIds is List of Guids;
var empIds = string.Format("{0}", string.Join(",", EmpIds.Select(x => $"'{x}'").ToArray()));

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var deletedRowsCount = connection.Execute("
                         DELETE FROM [Employee] WHERE EmployeeId in                         
                       (@empIds)",  new { empIds = empIds });
                        //EmployeeId is uniqueidentifier datatype in sqlserver db
}
```

Anybody tell me how to resolve this issue in dapper query for bulk delete.

Comment: Why are you doing the `string.Join`? Just pass in the Guid list directly (e.g. `new { empIds = EmpIds}`)

Comment: `new { empIds = EmpIds}` is enough, assuming `EmpIds` contains GUIDs and `EmployeeID` is a `uniqueidentifier` instead of a string field

Comment: @DavidG,@Panagiotis- I tried this method also by just passing Guid list directly, I am getting this error "incorrect syntax near ','" which is not taking comma separated guid array

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for `List<>` support in dapper is slightly different than in an actual T-SQL query. See: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

```sql
DELETE FROM [Employee] 
WHERE EmployeeId in @empIds
```

It does not require braces around the `IN` clause's parameter. And you can just pass an `IEnumerable<>`. Like this

```
new { empIds = new[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() } }
```